# How to use universal oauth redirect url?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a wordpress plugin to get some Youtube Data.

For that i need to get user's `google` `api`.

I am using `google-api-php-client-0.6.6`.

And i just made a Client ID at https://code.google.com/apis/console/

My Question is how can i get user api without giving redirect url. Because my plugin will use many users.

```
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
  FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
```

If i use this code but it's not working and give me this error

```
The redirect URI in the request: http://www.thewpdeveloper.com/wp-admin/admin.php did not match a registered redirect URI
```

I know if i give redirect url at `google` `api` console then its working. But i don't want to fix any url. Is that possible?

Comment: If you want to publish your plugin wordpress to any users of wordpress, then you dont have to care about the redirect url and just have to warn the users that they will need to register a google account to be able to use Youtube data. Then the users will give the redirect url themselves by putting the url of their wordpress website. So to continue to test your code, put your own redirect url of your own wordpress website. Hope this help.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get data from the you tube then why you are use google api? you can you you tube api and get data you want it...

https://developers.google.com/youtube/